# How to use runscript to load static library dynamically in Xcode？

Tags: ios, static-libraries, run-script

I have two static libraries, one for the device, and one for the simulator. And I don't want to merge them.I try to use runscript to load it dynamically.The code like it:
`if [ Lib/libmp3lame.a ]
then
rm -f Lib/libmp3lame.a
fi
if [ ${PLATFORM_NAME} = "iphoneos" ]
then
cp Lib/libmp3lame_arm.a Lib/libmp3lame.a
else
cp Lib/libmp3lame_simulator.a Lib/libmp3lame.a
fi`
But xcode can not find file.
[File location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF6ut.jpg)

Comment: Show the linker error.

Comment: The error is: cp: Lib/libmp3lame_arm.a: No such file or directory.   I find I use absolute path directly is still wrong.

Comment: Then how is that "But xcode can not find file"?

Comment: My English is very poor. What information do you need me to offer?

Comment: I need you to tell us what the error is.  In your question you say Xcode cannot find the file and in the comments it's the shell that cannot find the file.

Comment: OK! I run my runscript,and I find a error in Issuse Navigator. It said:"cp: Lib/libmp3lame.a: No such file or directory". So I edit the runscript code,replace relative path with absolute path. And run again, almost 8 errors show, i looks like  "_lame_close", referenced from:
"

Comment: OK, so you are running this script from within Xcode as a build step.  There is some detail you missed.  Next what is the *current working directory* set to when running this script?

Comment: I don't understand,my static lib absolute path is "/Users/lixinxin/Documents/Work/iOS/Daiqian/Daiqian/Daiqian/Lib/lame/libmp3lame.a",and project path is "/Users/lixinxin/Documents/Work/iOS/Daiqian/Daiqian/Daiqian.xcodeproj"

Comment: I am confused. I copied this script from another project. In another project to be able to operate normally.